# Simple word - synonym model, serialized attribute or association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, activerecord, model

I am working on a simple dictionary where I have words and synonyms to those words.

I am not sure which model is a better solution, working with a serialized attribute or association.

With association:

```
class ReservedWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :synonyms
end

class Synonym < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reserved_word
end
```

With serialization:

```
class ReservedWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :synonyms
end
```

In terms of data redundancy there isn't such a big problem because synonyms aren't supposed to repeat for other reserved words.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your sql query pattern expected to be like?

Using the `serialize` mechanism, you won't be able to *easily* query based on synonyms. Based on being able to reverse lookup `ReservedWord`'s based on their synonyms, I would recommend the `belongs_to`/`has_many` standard rails approach.

Comment: That is exactly the problem I came up with the serialization approach. I think I will stick to the standard model.